# Redirect 2nd level subfolders to subdomains

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

We have a WordPress multisite subdirectory system like this:

```
www.domain.com/demo/john/
www.domain.com/demo/james/
www.domain.com/demo/jane/
etc...
```

Each of those names is actual sub site and has its own sub pages. We have 120+ of such subsites, so you can guess there is a lot of pages/URL's.

We are changing it to subdomain multisite system, and now have to create redirections from old URL's to new ones (because system is linked to from many other places).

**QUESTION:**

**Can I have a single redirect block in htaccess to handle redirections for all of them?**

Example of what we need:

```
www.domain.com/demo/john/            ->  www.john.domain.com
www.domain.com/demo/john/about/      ->  www.john.domain.com/about/
www.domain.com/demo/donald/          ->  www.donald.domain.com
www.domain.com/demo/donald/contact/  ->  www.donald.domain.com/contact/
```

Comment: Please check this out [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45393491/how-to-set-up-redirect-for-subdomain-that-shares-the-subdirectory/45393673?noredirect=1#comment77748022_45393673](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45393491/how-to-set-up-redirect-for-subdomain-that-shares-the-subdirectory/45393673?noredirect=1#comment77748022_45393673)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, but will do more tests:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^demo/([^/]+)/(.*)$ http://$1.domain.com/$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

If anybody sees problem in this code let me know.