# How to set up redirect for subdomain that shares the subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I set up a subdirectory to host my wordpress site on Linux x86-Apache 2.2.x.  I also set up a subdomain to point to it.  Once the site was complete, I pointed the primary domain to the that subdirectory.  But now I need to redirect the subdomain to the domain.  How can I accoplish this?  I tried adding a 301 redirect to .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?subdomain.domain1\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.net/subfolder$1
```

but this just broke all my links on the domain.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What server do you use? Give more info...

Comment: @JackMov Apache.

Comment: Ok, which Linux? if it is Linux?

Comment: Linux x86 
Apache 2.2.x

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Here is the general info about Apache Virtual Hosting
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html

And here is the example with Ubuntu 16.04 (you can google any other). It is very easy, just follow the instructions.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

The point is you need to search info about VIRTUAL HOSTs (Apache).

Answer (score 0):

It looks likes you've got the right idea for the .htaccess redirect.

You'll now need to update all the links in your site to point to the new domain otherwise there's a chance you'll just create infinite redirect loops.

If, you can get into your admin you could use a tool like [Velvet blues](https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) otherwise & or if you want to do a more comprehensive job, I'd recommend using this standalone no-config required tool which updates all references in your database even if there are non-standard WP tables in use: [interconnect/it](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/comment-page-58/)